# Is this idea of "iterated congruence" something that has been studied before?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

So I have been working on an idea for a while and in the process it has become useful for me to do an "iterated" congruence residue with a fixed modulus.  A quick example to illustrate

Take the number 78 for example with a modulus of 4 , dividing:

78 = 19*4  + 2  (so it is congruent to 2 mod 4)

Now, repeat this process on the quotient until you get a quotient of zero:

19 = (4)(4) + 3

4 =  (4)(1) + 0

1 =  (4)(0) + 1

Then consider the sequence of the remainders in the order that we received them, for this example:  (2,3,0,1)

The reason I was looking at this is because with this sequence of remainders we can write the original number as powers of the modulus with those remainders as coefficients,
i.e.  78 = 2(1) + 3(4) + 0(16) + 1(64)

I couldn't help but notice how similar this is to the Euclidean algorithm as well!

I have only taken an undergraduate course in Number Theory but I don't remember seeing anything like that or in my year long graduate algebra sequence. So I am wondering if this sort of thing has been studied before?  Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: You just computed the digits in the base-$4$ representation of $78$. See [radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix). If you do this with modulus $10$, you get the usual decimal digits of a number.

Comment: Number theory would introduce $p$-adic expansion and even $p$-adic numbers. Wait and see. This is powerful in math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of your modulus $4$ in the used algorithm enables you to find a representation at *[base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)* $4$, namely
\begin{align*}
78 &= 1\cdot 64 + 0\cdot 16 +3 \cdot 4 + 2\cdot 1\\
&=1\cdot 4^\color{blue}{3}+0\cdot 4^\color{blue}{2}+3\cdot 4^\color{blue}{1} + 2\cdot 4^\color{blue}{0}
\end{align*}